# How to get full UART safely on Pi4?

Tags: pi-4, uart, config.txt, overclocking

I need to use full UART. I was using `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt` to achieve this but the name suggests it's for pi3, I have pi4. Should I use `miniuart-bt` instead, or `disable-bt` as I would want to turn Bluetooth off anyway? On the raspi website there is said:

> miniuart-bt switches the Bluetooth function to use the mini UART, and
> makes the first PL011 (UART0) the primary UART. [...]
> You must also set the VPU core clock to a fixed frequency using either
> force_turbo=1 or core_freq=250.

but later I've found this:

> Changing core_freq in config.txt is not supported on the Pi 4, any
> change from the default will almost certainly cause a failure to boot.
>
> It is recommended when overclocking to use the individual frequency
> settings (isp_freq, v3d_freq etc) rather than gpu_freq, as since it
> attempts to set core_freq (which cannot be changed on the Pi 4), it is
> not likely to have the desired effect.

So... what "individual frequency setting" will change "VPU clock" (there is no "vpu" word anywhere on the overclocking page)? Should I just go with `enable_turbo=1`? I would prefer to keep frequency default, I don't need 550MHz and it would shorten life expectancy of the device, right?

Does `disable-bt` solve my problem by itself? In the description there is nothing about clocks here:

> disable-bt disables the Bluetooth device and makes the first PL011
> (UART0) the primary UART. You must also disable the system service
> that initialises the modem, so it does not connect to the UART, using
> sudo systemctl disable hciuart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `/boot/overlays/README` for the up-to-date documentation, rather than old unreferenced posts.

The Pi4 has a totally new peripheral module, and older documentation no longer is relevant.

If it was me, I would leave BT alone and use one of the other 4 fully featured UART.

See [Raspberry Pi4 UART](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107780/8697)